# looping over images in a directory

Tags: linux, python-2.7, base64, ubuntu-14.04

I have images in the same directory with a python file, i am trying to loop over the images and convert them into  base64 but am getting this error.
Am using Ubuntu 14.0.4

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_to_base64.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(main())
  File "convert_to_base64.py", line 26, in main
    convert_to_base64()
  File "convert_to_base64.py", line 19, in convert_to_base64
    with open("*.jpg", "rb") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '*.jpg'
```

Here is my python code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import xlrd
import base64
import urllib
from datetime import datetime

reload(sys)  # to re-enable sys.setdefaultencoding()
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


def convert_to_base64():
    """
    Read all jpg images in a folder,
    and print them in base64
   """
    with open("*.jpg", "rb") as f:
        data = base64.b64decode(f.read())
    print data


def main():
    start_datetime = datetime.now()
    convert_to_base64()
    end_datetime = datetime.now()
    print '------------------------------------------------------'
    print 'Script started  : {}'.format(start_datetime)
    print 'Script finished: {}'.format(end_datetime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
    print('Done')
```

someone help me figure out what am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I looped for images in a  directory:

```
import os

pictures = []
for file in os.listdir("pictures"):
    if file[-3:].lower() in ["png"]:
        pictures.append(file)
```

Please refer to Python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html for more info on open() function:

> open() returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: open(filename, mode).